# Three.js: jsonLoader will not load textures no matter what

Tags: javascript, html, json, three.js, blender

Help, I'm getting multiple brain spasms trying to figure this out. I'm using r74 the most recent version threejs and I've created a model in blender and exported it using the most recent plugin. When I run my program, it loads the 3d file just fine, but it should also load the texture and apply it, right? Well it isn't, and according to everything I've seen online and every article I've read I'm doing it right. So what the heck! Is three.js broken right now?

Anyway, rants aside, here is my javascript code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Imported Model (Three.js)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel=stylesheet href="css/base.css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
  <script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
  <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="js/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
  <script src="js/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
  <script src="js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery code to display an information button and box when clicked. -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel=stylesheet href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel=stylesheet href="css/info.css"/>

    <script src="js/info.js"></script>
      <div id="infoButton"></div>
      <div id="infoBox" title="Demo Information">
   This three.js demo is part of a collection at
   <a href="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/">http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/</a>
</div>

<div id="ThreeJS" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>
<script>

// MAIN

// standard global variables
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

// custom global variables
var android;

init();
animate();

// FUNCTIONS        
function init() 
{
// SCENE
scene = new THREE.Scene();
// CAMERA
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
scene.add(camera);
camera.position.set(0,150,400);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
// RENDERER
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
// EVENTS
THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });
// CONTROLS
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
// STATS
stats = new Stats();
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
// LIGHT
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(-100,200,100);
scene.add(light);
// SKYBOX/FOG
var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9999ff, side: THREE.BackSide } );
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
// scene.add(skyBox);
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x9999ff, 0.00025 );


//JSON LOADER HERE !!!!!!!

// Note: if imported model appears too dark,
//   add an ambient light in this file
//   and increase values in model's exported .js file
//    to e.g. "colorAmbient" : [0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load("map/titled.json", addModelToScene );
jsonLoader.setTexturePath("http://localhost:8080/map/");
// addModelToScene function is called back after model has loaded


var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
scene.add(ambientLight);

}

function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) 
{
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.scale.set(10,10,10);
scene.add( mesh );
}

function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
    update();
}

function update()
{
if ( keyboard.pressed("z") ) 
{ 
    // do something
}

controls.update();
stats.update();
}

function render() 
{
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Json file (titled.json):

```
"materials":[{
    "DbgIndex":81,
    "DbgColor":15658734,
    "depthTest":true,
    "shading":"phong",
    "wireframe":false,
    "depthWrite":true,
    "transparent":false,
    "DbgName":"Material.002",
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "visible":true,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "opacity":1,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "specularCoef":50,
    "blending":"NormalBlending"
},{
    "DbgIndex":117,
    "DbgColor":15658734,
    "depthTest":true,
    "shading":"phong",
    "wireframe":false,
    "depthWrite":true,
    "transparent":false,
    "DbgName":"Material",
    "colorSpecular":[0.5,0.5,0.5],
    "visible":true,
    "colorEmissive":[0,0,0],
    "opacity":1,
    "colorDiffuse":[0.64,0.64,0.64],
    "specularCoef":50,
    "blending":"NormalBlending"
}],
```

**--- edit --- in response to gaitat ---**

I know.

Earlier I was using the old version of the blender plug-in "io_mesh_three" and I would choose the same settings as I'm choosing now, and there would a be reference to my texture in the json file. However, I recently found that the old blender plug-in, according to mrdoob found here: (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender), had been completely replaced. So I installed the new plug-in, and with the new exporter options ui I could't quite tell if I was using the same settings or not, but the reference would no longer show up, so I figured it just didn't need the reference. I think I'm having trouble understanding what's happening because there isn't a lot of support online for the more recent versions of three.js. Most of what I've found has been support for the older versions, so I'm just fishing to try and find a solution to get my code to load my json file AND apply the texture.

Comment: your json materials do not have a reference to a texture

Comment: how do i make it have a reference to a texture

Comment: Okay, after fiddling with this a little bit more, I finally got my texture to load. I finally found the right settings for exporting from blender. Looks like that was my problem all along. Next time I'll think to be sure of my export settings. Thank you for your help gaitat.